# jQuery UI sortable: get new item position preventing DOM changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list on my page. I would like to know just the user's intension: what item he drags and where, i.e. old and new (potential) position of the dragged element.

But I DON'T want jQuery-sortable to actually change my DOM -- I want to do it myself. Here is the example:

```js
$(".sortable-list").sortable({
  items: ".sortable-item",
  stop: function (event, ui) {
    // prevent DOM changes
    $(this).sortable('cancel');
    // get the indices
    var oldIndex = $(this).find('.sortable-item').index(ui.item);
    var newIndex = 'how?'; // this is the question
  }
});
```

I know I can calculate new position using `ui.originalPosition` and `ui.position`, but I believe jQuery-sortable has already done this work since it puts a placeholder in a valid place, so I just want to get the value.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, while I was writing a question I have actually found the solution.

It turns out that jQuery-sortable does change the DOM before I call `$(this).sortable('cancel')`. What this call actually does is *reverting* the changes plugin has done.

Here's the working code:

```js
$(".sortable-list").sortable({
  items: ".sortable-item",
  stop: function (event, ui) {
    var newIndex = $(this).find('.sortable-item').index(ui.item);
    $(this).sortable('cancel');  // revert changes
    var oldIndex = $(this).find('.sortable-item').index(ui.item);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution -- it helped me solve my problem :)

Comment: @noistseuq: I believe you are partially correct. In my experience, IE 7 and 8 do not revert the DOM to its original from in the jQueryui sortable's stop and receive events on call of cancel. It does it some time later.